# WxPython changing the shape of bitmap button

Tags: python, wxpython

Hi I'm sort new to wxPython and still in the process of learning. I'm trying to make a bitmap button using a particular image like this for example: http://i.min.us/idk3Uy.png

The catch is I want to retain the original shape of the image in the button, like a circular button for example instead of a rectangular one (which is default).

I want to know how to do that exactly or if it is possible to do that at all; I did take a look at the documentation and I've found the style constant wx.BU_EXACTFIT removes the unnecessary borders...but it's still not in the desirable shape that I want it to be.

Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're probably going to have to implement a custom control for this. I've done my fair share of custom wxPython controls, so I went ahead and wrote a `ShapedButton` class for you. =)

To run this demo, you just need three images:

- button-normal.png
- button-pressed.png
- button-disabled.png

The three images are used depending on the state of the button. Only the "normal" one is required, but you probably want to at least provide "normal" and "pressed" so the user gets feedback when clicking.

The control only responds to clicks in non-transparent areas of the normal bitmap. It properly fires the `EVT_BUTTON` event when clicked and released.

Enjoy!

[image: Demo Screenshot]

```
import wx

class ShapedButton(wx.PyControl):
    def __init__(self, parent, normal, pressed=None, disabled=None):
        super(ShapedButton, self).__init__(parent, -1, style=wx.BORDER_NONE)
        self.normal = normal
        self.pressed = pressed
        self.disabled = disabled
        self.region = wx.RegionFromBitmapColour(normal, wx.Color(0, 0, 0, 0))
        self._clicked = False
        self.SetBackgroundStyle(wx.BG_STYLE_CUSTOM)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_SIZE, self.on_size)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.on_paint)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.on_left_down)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DCLICK, self.on_left_dclick)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_UP, self.on_left_up)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MOTION, self.on_motion)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_LEAVE_WINDOW, self.on_leave_window)
    def DoGetBestSize(self):
        return self.normal.GetSize()
    def Enable(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ShapedButton, self).Enable(*args, **kwargs)
        self.Refresh()
    def Disable(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ShapedButton, self).Disable(*args, **kwargs)
        self.Refresh()
    def post_event(self):
        event = wx.CommandEvent()
        event.SetEventObject(self)
        event.SetEventType(wx.EVT_BUTTON.typeId)
        wx.PostEvent(self, event)
    def on_size(self, event):
        event.Skip()
        self.Refresh()
    def on_paint(self, event):
        dc = wx.AutoBufferedPaintDC(self)
        dc.SetBackground(wx.Brush(self.GetParent().GetBackgroundColour()))
        dc.Clear()
        bitmap = self.normal
        if self.clicked:
            bitmap = self.pressed or bitmap
        if not self.IsEnabled():
            bitmap = self.disabled or bitmap
        dc.DrawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0)
    def set_clicked(self, clicked):
        if clicked != self._clicked:
            self._clicked = clicked
            self.Refresh()
    def get_clicked(self):
        return self._clicked
    clicked = property(get_clicked, set_clicked)
    def on_left_down(self, event):
        x, y = event.GetPosition()
        if self.region.Contains(x, y):
            self.clicked = True
    def on_left_dclick(self, event):
        self.on_left_down(event)
    def on_left_up(self, event):
        if self.clicked:
            x, y = event.GetPosition()
            if self.region.Contains(x, y):
                self.post_event()
        self.clicked = False
    def on_motion(self, event):
        if self.clicked:
            x, y = event.GetPosition()
            if not self.region.Contains(x, y):
                self.clicked = False
    def on_leave_window(self, event):
        self.clicked = False

def main():
    def on_button(event):
        print 'Button was clicked.'
    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    frame = wx.Frame(None, -1, 'Shaped Button Demo')
    panel = wx.Panel(frame, -1)
    button = ShapedButton(panel, 
        wx.Bitmap('button-normal.png'), 
        wx.Bitmap('button-pressed.png'), 
        wx.Bitmap('button-disabled.png'))
    button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, on_button)
    sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    sizer.AddStretchSpacer(1)
    sizer.Add(button, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
    sizer.AddStretchSpacer(1)
    panel.SetSizer(sizer)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I can't say how thankful I'm to you, I even asked on IRC @Freenode on #wxpython and didn't get any response...your code seems to work perfectly and I'll have to take a closer look at it. Initially when I ran my code on Windows the button apparently was rounded but on Linux it seemed to have a rectangular shape after trying out your code the problem seems to be solved. Many thanks!

Comment: Any Fix suggestion for this issue? 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\mywxpython\bitmaptest.py", line 112, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\mywxpython\bitmaptest.py", line 95, in main
    button = ShapedButton(
  File "C:\mywxpython\bitmaptest.py", line 10, in __init__
    self.region = wx.RegionFromBitmapColour(normal, wx.Color(0, 0, 0, 0))
AttributeError: module 'wx' has no attribute 'RegionFromBitmapColour'
[Finished in 139ms]

Comment: The updated script (with wx.App and wx.Control fixes): https://web.archive.org/web/20230401162906/https://pastebin.com/aegQgWjQ. Thanks!