# How do I change the style of a toggle button in wxPython?

Tags: user-interface, wxpython, togglebutton

I never figured out how to use the style parameter. Can someone tell me how to use it to make nicer toggle buttons? Or if you can't use it directly, is there a way to do it manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
import wx
class MyForm(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "Toggle")
        panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)
        self.button = wx.ToggleButton(panel, label="Press Me")
        self.button.Bind(wx.EVT_TOGGLEBUTTON, self.onToggle)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.button, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        panel.SetSizer(sizer)

    def onToggle(self, event):
        if self.button.GetValue() == True:
            self.button.SetLabel("On")
        else:
            self.button.SetLabel("Off")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyForm()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: I know how to change the text on it but I wanted to change its shape. From the example you gave me I would like to not make it look rectangular but rather circular for example. is that possible to do with style?

Comment: I didn't get that from "nicer", perhaps you could use a wx.BitmapButton(). That may be what you are after. As far as I know the standard button shapes are just that, standard.

Comment: Yello, look at shapedbutton in AGW library or look at this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6449709/wxpython-changing-the-shape-of-bitmap-button

Comment: Thanks for your help. I got the buttons working the way I wanted them to :)